# EntityFramework DataBaseFirst подключение (скафолдинг) только нескольких таблиц из бд

Tags: sql, entity-framework, .net-core, scaffolding

Есть БД, при команде 
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=...
EF создает модели для всей БД, но необходимости в этом нет. Как ограничить список таблиц, для которых необходимо выполнить преобразование в модели.

Answer (score 1):

используйте параметр `--table` или `--schema`

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "connstring" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --outputDir Models -table dbo.MyTable
```

Подробнее: [.net core cli](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold), [Package Manager Console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext)

Comment: Спасибо, как то пропустил этот параметр. Таблицы можно указывать через запятую, поправьте Ваш ответ для остальных.